# Adding GCM push service notification to an existing Android application

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, google-cloud-messaging

**Hi i have already built the native GCM application for Android which is working very fine in all my android devices.
But i want to further use this GCM service like i want to integrate this GCM service with my existing Android app as for for testing i have already done my server for GCM but i am lagging behind all because of the Client side implementation. i have been trying to get the relevant information regarding my project but i couldn't be able to find an resource of Client Side Implementation on the Existing Android App. If anyone could provide me any link i would be very much grateful.
Thanks in advance**

**Here is my my server side code for GCM**

```
<?php

class GCM {

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

    /**
     * Sending Push Notification
     */
    public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
        // include config
        include_once './config.php';

        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged this with PhoneGap but you do not really say if this is a normal Android app or something else? If it's a standard Android application there's a really [simple step-by-step tutorial on the official Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#android-app).

If this is a PhoneGap app there's a bunch of questions on SO related to GCM. Do a search a see if any of them help you get started.

UPDATE: Ok, since this is a PhoneGap app I had to look up some stuff. I have a good understanding of how GCM works in an Android app and it seems like it's the same sequence of events that you have to do in a PhoneGap app. You mentioned that you followed Mark Nutter's example. I assume you mean that you're using the [GitHub project](https://github.com/marknutter)?

If this is the case, the interesting bit for you is the [GCMIntentService](https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova/blob/master/src/com/cordova2/gcm/GCMIntentService.java). This is the piece of code responsible for handling GCM registration and GCM messages. In GCMIntentService there's an [onRegistered()](https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova/blob/master/src/com/cordova2/gcm/GCMIntentService.java#L23) method that gets called when the app successfully registers with GCM (I'm not sure if the registration is done automatically or if you have to invoke it yourself). Anyway, you will get a registration id and it is this id that you need to send to your own server. If you take a look at [line #39](https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova/blob/master/src/com/cordova2/gcm/GCMIntentService.java#L39) you can see that the plugin sends a JSON object back to your PhoneGap app. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "event":"registered",
    "regid":"a very long registration id that you should send to your server"
}
```

Handle this JSON callback on the Javascript-side and you should be good to go!

Comment: Yes basically i am doing the android app project using phonegap corodova 2.2.0 nothing is happening for the moment till now i have followed Mark Nutter's method of including the GCM plugin in my app but that doesn't work for me. i have done already the serverside GCM in php. but the main difficulty i am facing is in the client side the integration of GCM seems not working the project id i have included . But where i have to put the server there seems no where i have to put my sever's URL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes basically i am doing the android app project using phonegap corodova 2.2.0 nothing is happening for the moment till now i have followed Mark Nutter's method of including the GCM plugin in my app but that doesn't work for me.
i have done already the serverside GCM in php.
but the main difficulty i am facing is in the client side the integration of GCM seems not working the project id i have included . But where i have to put the server there seems no where i have to put my sever's URL.